# sftp equivalent of lftp command returns Permission denied

Tags: unix, ftp, sftp, lftp

My task is to port working `lftp` command to it's `sftp` equivalent. I have a private key generated at `~/key.key`.

Working lftp command:

```
lftp -u Username,'pass' xxx.xxx.xx.xx ssl:key-file key.key
```

Not working sftp equivalent:

```
sftp -i ~/key.key Username@xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

The sftp command asks me for a password, i provide the same one available in `lftp` command and the process exits with `Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)`.

Is there any way i can debug what's happening or maybe something very obvious I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be use using FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL) with `lftp`, not SFTP (over SSH).

OpenSSH `sftp` is SFTP-only, it does not support FTPS. Those are completely different protocols.

Comment: oh gosh, that's embarassing but i was not aware SFTP and FTPS are different things. Thank you for your reply!